# Once softlayer id switchs to IBM id, can i use Softlayer API?

Tags: api, ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-infrastructure, account

recently, i received the email about switching to IBMid in 30days.
i am using JAVA API provided by softlayer.

after swithcing, can i continually use JAVA API based softlayer ID ?

if this can't use, how should i do ?

Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes you can still use it, you just need to make sure that you are using the correct username and API key you can check that information in the control portal in your profile details https://control.softlayer.com/account/user/profile